# Como recordar usuario en Android utilizando el componente WebView

Tags: android, webservice, webview, aplicación-movil

Estoy haciendo una aplicación con el componente WebView, en mi pagina hay un login y al momento de entrar con la clave, me gustaría que se quede guardada la clave para no ingresar nuevamente cada vez que se requiera entrar.

He visto tanto CookieManager, SharedPreferences, Savedpassword, etc. Pero no logro comprender cual me podría servir y como implementarlo en mi codigo, si alguien puede ayudarme de ante mano, muchas gracias.

**MainActivity:**

```
import androidx.annotation.RequiresApi;
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.os.Build;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.webkit.WebResourceRequest;
import android.webkit.WebSettings;
import android.webkit.WebView;
import android.webkit.WebViewClient;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private WebView webView;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        webView = findViewById(R.id.webView);

        webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());
        webView.loadUrl("https://miurl.cl");

        WebSettings webSettings = webView.getSettings();
        webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);


        //Abrir links externos

        webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient(){
            @RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP)
            public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, WebResourceRequest webResource) {
                if (webResource != null && (webResource.getUrl().toString().startsWith("https://www.google.cl/maps/place/"))) {
                    view.getContext().startActivity(
                            new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, webResource.getUrl()));
                    return true;
                } else {
                    return false;
                }
            }
        });

    }
    //Boton Back
    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {

        if(webView.canGoBack()){
            webView.goBack();
        }else{
            super.onBackPressed();
    }

    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Para esto se tenían dos métodos, los cuales por cuestión de seguridad fueron marcados como obsoletos.

> **[setSavePassword(boolean save)](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebSettings#setSavePassword(boolean))** Este método fue desaprobado en el nivel 18 de la API. El almacenamiento de contraseñas en WebView no se
> admitirá en futuras versiones.

y

> **[setSaveFormData(boolean save)](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebSettings#setSaveFormData(boolean))** Este método fue desaprobado en el nivel 26 de API. En Android O y posteriormente, esta función no tiene
> ningún efecto, los datos del formulario se guardarán en el servicio de
> autocompletar de la plataforma, si corresponde.

Puedes también agregar en la forma de tu página el atributo `autocomplete="on"`, con esto recordaría los valores, ejemplo

```
<form action="/action_page.php" autocomplete="on">
```

**Pero lo recomendable por seguridad es no guardar el password y provocar que el usuario lo tenga que escribir. Debes tener cuidado en evitar guardar información sensible porque tu aplicación podría ser dada de baja**